# List to dataframe conversion in R: Keeping List indexes

Tags: r, dataframe

I am transforming a list of character vectors into a dataframe using R. How can I get the list indices also into the dataframe?

```
list1 = list(c('kip','kroket'),'ei','koe')

print(list1)
##[[1]]
##[1] "kip"    "kroket"

##[[2]]
##[1] "ei"

##[[3]]
##[1] "koe"

df = data.frame(col1 = unlist(x))

print(df)
##   col1
##1    kip
##2 kroket
##3     ei
##4    koe
```

The preferred output would look like this:

```
##   col1    col2
##1    kip   1
##2 kroket   1
##3     ei   2
##4    koe   3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An idea via base R,

```
data.frame(v1 = unlist(list1), v2 = rep(seq(length(list1)), lengths(list1)))

#      v1 v2
#1    kip  1
#2 kroket  1
#3     ei  2
#4    koe  3
```

Answer (score 5):

We can name the list along with it's length and then use `stack`

```
names(list1) <- seq_along(list1)
stack(list1)

#  values ind
#1    kip   1
#2 kroket   1
#3     ei   2
#4    koe   3
```

Or another option could be using `enframe` and `unnest`

```
list1 %>% tibble::enframe() %>% tidyr::unnest()
```

Answer (score 5):

tidyverse method

```
list1 %>% map(~as_tibble(.)) %>% bind_rows(.id="index")

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  index value
  <chr> <chr>
1 1     kip
2 1     kroket
3 2     ei
4 3     koe
```